# Finding the interval for which $f(x) =x+2\sin(x)$ is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometric-series, monotone-functions

I have a the function $f(x)=x+2\sin(x)$ and I want to find the increasing interval.

So I find the derivative when it's larger than 0.

Hence $f'(x)>0$ when $2\cos(x)>-1$.

So by figuring when $f'(x) = 0$ and got it to

$\cos(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ so $x=\frac{4\pi}{3}$

according to the formula the increasing interval is between
 $(-\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n,\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n)$

I don't really understand how that's possible. Shouldn't it during some instance decrease within the interval? Is there some program where I could visualise the increase between these points?

Comment: You want to figure out when $f'(x )> 0$. You have only figured out when it is *equal to* $0$. Set $\cos x > \frac{-1}2$ and find the desired range.

Comment: Please fix the title.

Comment: You have the correct inequality $2\cos x >-1$. But if you just sketch the cosine function, you will see because of periodicity, that there are many intervals where this is true. You got only one of the endpoints of the intervals, but with trigonometric functions you should in most cases  expect infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Hence the $2pi*n$ but at $n=0$ the curve between $(-\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n,\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n)$ should always be increasing but I would like to see it.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B2+sin(x)

Comment: cheers that helped. However I now graphed both functions on the same graph and got this http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4KzJzaW4oeCkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiMSsyY29zKHgpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwfV0- 
I noticed that on $f(x)=x+2sinx$ it is increasing between $(-2,2)$ should't the derivative $f(x)=1+2cos(x)$ also be curve increasing between (-2,2) too?

Comment: The derivative should be *positive* on that interval. You have to organize your solutions $\pm 4\pi/3 +2\pi n$ in correct order: $-4\pi/3+2\pi = +2\pi/3$ and $4\pi/3-2\pi=-2\pi/3$ so the "first" interval of increasing will be $(-2\pi/3,+2\pi/3)$ (you know it's increasing and not decreasing by checking $2\cos 0>-1$). From here on, the intervals alternate between increasing and decreasing.

Comment: I understand now. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this diagram will help:

[image]

Comment: It did actually. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve $\;1+2\cos x>0\iff\cos x>_\frac12$.

Solve it first on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Making a sketch on the unit circle leads to
$$-\frac{2\pi}3<x<\frac{2\pi}3,$$
whence the general solution
$$\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf Z}\Bigl(-\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi,<\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi\Bigr).$$